# Java boolean expression concurrency behavior

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

Please consider the following situation.
There are two `AtomicInteger` fields in some class:

```
private final AtomicInteger first = new AtomicInteger();
private final AtomicInteger second = new AtomicInteger();
```

Then I have something like this:

```
boolean equal = first.get() == second.get();
```

So the question is how exactly this expression is evaluated? Can variables change values during its evaluation? For example is it possible that both `first` and `second` variables are equal when we start to evaluate the expression, but between evaluation of `first.get()` and `second.get()` some of them changes so `equal` evaluates to `false`? Or the expression is evaluated atomically by comparing snapshots of the variables on invocation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Comment: @Hackerman Those are `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`'s highly volatile fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can variables change values during its evaluation?

Absolutely. The calls to `first.get()` and `second.get()` are made independently of each other. If `second` changes after `first.get()` is completed but before `second.get()` is started, the value of `second` as of the time of evaluating its `get()` would be used.

In fact, in your scenario there is no difference between `first` and `second` being `AtomicInteger`s and using regular `int`s in `first == second` comparison.

Comment: The OP actually asked the wrong question. The actual question should have been, “is there a way to *atomically update* two `AtomicInteger` instances?” Since there is no such way, the question about reading becomes meaningless. Even if we were able to atomically read two `AtomicInteger` instances, it could still happen in the middle of an update. And since the result of `first.get() == second.get()` could be outdated right the next CPU cycle, it has not much use anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You're assuming correctly. Only `first.get()` and `second.get()` are atomic, each on it's own. So the value of second can change after you've already called `first.get()`.

You would need to synchronize or otherwise lock both `first` and `second` to assure atomicity across both.